# Unable to Connect Cloud SQL using PHP Google App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I just deploy the following app. And i receive the error. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
$instance_name = "mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/My_Project_ID:google-cloud-instance";
$c = new mysqli(null, "root", "My_Password", 'My_DB_Name', 0, $instance_name);
if ($c->connect_error) {
    echo $c->connect_error;
    $c = null;
} else {    
    echo "Connected ";
}
```

And I receive the error in browser like

```
Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Answer (score 0):

The [socket argument](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) doesn't say anything about a prefix:

```
$socket_path = "/cloudsql/My_Project_ID:google-cloud-instance";
$c = new mysqli(null, "my-user", "my-password", 'my-db', $socket_path);
```